# Change CheckBox checked with animation in RecyclerView

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

If the user clicks on a `CheckBox`, it runs a very nice animation (on Lollipop).

However if i invoke `myCheckBox.toggle()` programatically, it does not run the animation, but immediately shows the new state. Is there a way to run the smooth animation when changing the checked state programatically?

**EDIT**: it turned out it does not run the animation when this is a `RecyclerView` item. It runs otherwise...

**EDIT2**: the problem lies in the item animator. It seems it kills of all other animations before starting its own. I guess [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.java#L430) exact line causes the problem.

Comment: Did you try `myCheckBox.performClick();`? Maybe that would give you different results?

Comment: Maybe you can read the source code and achieve it yourself.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Did you solve it? Do you know how to make the toggling animate programmatically ?

Comment: I managed to resolve it since then, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, you have to disable the default change animation, which kills all the other animations on the list items views. Please note this will remove the default cross-fade.

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) RecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is a year old, but maybe we can get the discussion going again. `RecyclerView` still kills animation as of yet, and as I couldn't find any easy answer to this question I will gave it a try.

It is possible to animate inside the list using a `Handler` for the `MainThread`.

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        holder.mCheckBox.toggle();
     }
});
```

This may be an overkill but works for any kind of animation, even inside `onBindViewHolder`. I strongly suggest checking if the animation should play beforehand, or it will play even when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how useful it will be. Anyway, I have case when I need to change `CheckBox` state after click on item in `RecyclerView`. And I had the same issue with an animation. So what I've done.

- item is clicked, I call `mCheckBox.toggle()`
- update item inside list (checked state is kept in the item of list)
- need to update adapter (data was changed) using [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html)

The animation doesn't work if just call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myCheckBox.setChecked(!myCheckBox.isChecked(), true);`